# Need to convert my SQL query into hibernate criteria query for unrelated entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I Need to convert my SQL query into hibernate criteria query from different tables.
there are no relation between tables. common columns are there but with different name.
Here's the query :

```
select *
from table1 aa
left join table2 ab
    on aa.sequence = ab.newsequence
left join table3 ac
    on ab.poNumber= ac.number
where ab.date is null;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use CriteriaAPI? SQL is fine

Comment: The whole application is designed with criteria query. I am implementing a change in existing criteria.

Comment: You can use Join...On like you do in SQL